# How to get all options in a drop-down list by Selenium WebDriver using C#?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to both C# and Selenium WebDriver.

I know how to select/click on an option in a drop-down list, but I've a problem before that.  Since the drop-down list is dynamically generated, I have to get all options/values from the list before running each case.

Is there anyone kindly tell me how to get all values/options from a drop-down list.  I'm using IE and I didn't find any class which supports method to get values/options in Selenium.IE namespace for C#.

My example:
A list contains several time zones:

```
<TD>
  <select name = "time_zone">
    <option value "-09:00"><script>timezone.Alaska</script></option>
    <option value "+00:00"><script>timezone.England</script></option>
    <option value "+02:00"><script>timezone.Greece</script></option>
    <option value "+05:30"><script>timezone.India</script></option>
  </select>
<TD>
```

This is a drop-down list in an IE page and how to get the dynamically generated time zone list?

My code:

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='time_zone']"));
List<IWebElement> options = elem.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));
```

C# just pops an Error:
Cannot implicitly covert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can try using the WebDriver.Support **SelectElement** found in **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.Selected** namespace to access the option list of a select list:

```cs
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='time_zone']"));

SelectElement selectList = new SelectElement(elem);
IList<IWebElement> options = selectList.Options;
```

You can then access each option as an IWebElement, such as:

```
IWebElement firstOption = options[0];
Assert.AreEqual(firstOption.GetAttribute("value"), "-09:00");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));

select.getOptions();//will get all options as List<WebElement>
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you reference the WebDriver.Support.dll assembly to gain access to the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement dropdown helper class.  See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/2280128e2fa727db/c226b53b74c64f8d) for additional details.

Edit: In this screenshot, you can see that I can get the options just fine.  Is IE opening up when you create a new InternetExplorerDriver?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've already added WebDriver.dll and WebDriver.Support.dll into the reference.

Comment: anyway, thank you all the same.  I'm still looking for solutions.

Comment: Your code should work if you use implicit typing: var options = elem.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));

Comment: jmac, thank you.  I tried, but it still returns the type of the node rather than the value/text of the option.  I also tried: var tz = elem.FindElment(xx).Text.ToString();  It returns " ", just a space.  Do you know why? thx.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code in Java to get all options in dropdown list.

```
WebElement sel = myD.findElement(By.name("dropdown_name"));
List<WebElement> lists = sel.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for(WebElement element: lists)  
    {
        String var2 = tdElement.getText();
        System.out.println(var2);
    }
```

Hope it may helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selenium.Support` to use the `SelectElement` class, this class have a property "Options" that is what you are looking for, I created an extension method to convert your web element to a select element

```
public static SelectElement AsDropDown(this IWebElement webElement)
{
    return new SelectElement(webElement);
}
```

then you could use it like this

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='time_zone']"));
var options = elem.AsDropDown().Options
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IList<IWebElement>` instead of `List<IWebElement>`.

For instance:

```
IList<IWebElement> options = elem.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));
foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{
    Console.WriteLine(option.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a cast exception.  Can you try converting your result to a list
i.e. `elem.findElements(xx).toList` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried in this way.  But when I printed the elements of the List, all element of List[i] is "OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement", which is the type but not the value.

Comment: Thank you all the same.  I found a method in Selenium namespace called "GetSelectOptions", but I didn't how to use it with class IWebElement or InternetExplorerWebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

```
To get all the dropdown values you can use List.

List<string> lstDropDownValues = new List<string>();
int iValuescount = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("\html\....\select\option"))

for(int ivalue = 1;ivalue<=iValuescount;ivalue++)
 {
  string strValue = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("\html\....\select\option["+ ivalue +"]"));
  lstDropDownValues.Add(strValue); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement drop_down =driver.findElement(By.id("Category"));
Select se = new Select(drop_down);
for(int i=0 ;i<se.getOptions().size(); i++)
System.out.println(se.getOptions().get(i).getAttribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("inst_state"));
        Select s = new Select(element);
        List <WebElement> elementcount = s.getOptions();

        System.out.println(elementcount.size());
        for(int i=0 ;i<elementcount.size();i++)
        {
            String value = elementcount.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(value);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all options in a drop-down list by Selenium WebDriver C#:

```
SelectElement TimeZoneSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("time_zone")));
IList<IWebElement> ElementCount = TimeZoneSelect.Options;
int ItemSize = ElementCount.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < ItemSize; i++)
{
    String ItemValue = ElementCount.ElementAt(i).Text;
    Console.WriteLine(ItemValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the desired select webelement here and you can use getOptions() that helps you to get all the options of the drop-down.
Now you can get all the elements one-by-one using loop and you can print it on the console.

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath>")));
// getting the list of options in the dropdown with getOptions()
List <WebElement> op = s.getOptions();
int size = op.size();
for(int i =0; i<size ; i++)
{
   String options = op.get(i).getText();
   System.out.println(options);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answer are not suitable. Please consider adding some explanation on how and why your code should solve the problem.

Comment: @XouDo done now. Thanks for the suggestion :)