# Data extraction from javascript rendered webpage with python

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I'm trying to extract all the data from "http://www.tesourotransparente.gov.br/visualizacoes/series-temporais", but can't figure out how to get the dropdown options names and jsons urls. I know how to find them by inspecting elements, but I'd like to automate the download for all the data instead of manually looking for each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all elements from drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768318/how-can-i-get-all-elements-from-drop-down-list)

Comment: Not really. Already tried select but I'm still having trouble in finding and selecting the items

Comment: your question was `can't figure out how to get the dropdown options names and jsons urls` which is duplicate to the other question I linked. So maybe you need to articulate your questions a little better. Also please post relevant code, html, and errors / exceptions so that we understand what you want. As it's written, this question cannot get any helpful answers