# How to store values from a list to arraylist in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to store the values from a list to a global array for later use/verify in other pages.

My element looks like below:

Tried array list which gives only the 1st line, but I have multiple items in the list.

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span style="margin-left:2%">Veena Pujari (Attorney)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span style="margin-left:2%">Ranjit Nayak (Accredited Representative)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to pull the values ex:

```
List<WebElement> PMPageCMList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]"));
            int totalcms = PMPageCMList.size();
            for(int i=1;i<=totalcms;i++){
                CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div"+"["+i+"]"+"/span")).getText());
                System.out.println(CaseManagersreceivingreminders);
```

Comment: what is printed?

Comment: For the record: follow java naming conventions. Variable/field names should go camelCase in Java. So that (very hard to read) name CaseManagersreceivingreminders might better be caseManagersReceivingReminders !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Thanks all!

Note: CaseManagersreceivingreminders- is a global arraylist stored

```
List<WebElement> PMPageCMList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div"));
        int totalcms = PMPageCMList.size();
        for(int i=1;i<=totalcms;i++){
            CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div"+"["+i+"]"+"/span")).getText());
            System.out.println(CaseManagersreceivingreminders);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the following values:

```
Veena Pujari (Attorney)
Ranjit Nayak (Accredited Representative)
```

you might want to amend your [XPath expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) to look for [`<i>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp) which [contains](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)  `fa-user` [class](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) and retrieve its [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property for its [following-sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling)

```
List<String> PMPageCMList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'fa-user')]/following-sibling::span"))
        .stream()
        .map(user -> user.getAttribute("innerText"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
PMPageCMList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: this worked fine with little change in my xpath. Looks cool now. Can we match this values with the values stored in an array list and how please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line :

```
CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div"+"["+i+"]"+"/span")).getText());
```

To be :

```
CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2])[" +i +"]")).getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
CaseManagersreceivingreminders.add(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@id='collapseCM']/div[2]/div[2]/div/span)["+i+"]")).getText());
```

When you specify xpath in "(.//tag//subtag)[index]" format, it works more like a list
But on the contrary, ".//tag//subtag[index]" searches for the nth child under a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are looking to print the values e.g. **Veena Pujari (Attorney)**, **Ranjit Nayak (Accredited Representative)**, etc, so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use *Java8*'s `stream()` and `map()` and can use the following solution:

```
List<String> myValues = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='clearfix']/i[@class='fa fa-user']//following::span[1]"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(myValues);
```

> You can find a relevant  discussion in [How to extract the dynamic values of the id attributes of the table elements using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707227/how-to-extract-the-dynamic-values-of-the-id-attributes-of-the-table-elements-usi/55707593#55707593)

Comment: tried your method xpath, its going to next section which i dont need to store.

Comment: @ranjitnayak Updated the answer, let me know the status