# Iterate over columns in a table header row and print out the text using Selenium Java

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to iterate through a list of columns for a table header row, and need to print out the text of the element (`getText()`).  How can this be done when there are many columns (`td`) for the specific table header row?  Below is the XPATH and a screenshot showing the columns (count of 54 columns):

XPATH expresssion for table header row:  `//*[@id="accuracyTableWrapper"]/table/thead/tr`

XPATH expresssion  for table column:  `//*[@id="accuracyTableWrapper"]/table/thead/tr/td` (where there are 54 instances of this)

Screenshot:
[image]

How can this be done efficiently in order to properly print out the text for each `td`?  Please let me know for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML...

[image: html]

the elements seems to be dynamic elements, so to print the desired texts ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707593/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#accuracyTableWrapper > table > thead > tr td")));
  for(WebElement element : elements)
  {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
  }
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id="accuracyTableWrapper"]/table/thead/tr//td")));
  for(WebElement element : elements)
  {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
  }
  ```

Using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#accuracyTableWrapper > table > thead > tr td"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id="accuracyTableWrapper"]/table/thead/tr//td"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion and it makes sense to include the WebDriverWait.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will print all the text within the `td` nodes:

```
List<WebElement> tdList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"accuracyTableWrapper\"]/table/thead/tr/td"));
        for (WebElement element : tdList) {
            System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```