# Trying to use a custom css selector to get all options in a dropdown list using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

The dropdowns in our webpage do not use the common select tags or Li tags. this is making it difficult to extract and store the list items text in a WebElement list. Here is an image of the DOM and drop down list Vs and I also provide the code I am trying to write

`WebDriver driver = getDriver();

```
    List<WebElement> teachers = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rc-virtual-list-holder-inner>div>div"));
    for (WebElement myElement : teachers) {
        
        System.out.println(myElement.getText());`
```

[image]

Comment: Can you either share the text based HTML or the URL of the application? Also, share the error stack.

Comment: You might try xpath of: //div[contains(@class, "ant-select-item")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML...

[image: html]

to print the item texts ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707593/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.rc-virtual-list-holder-inner div[title] > div")));
  for(WebElement element : elements)
  {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
  }
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class="rc-virtual-list-holder-inner"]//div[@title]/div")));
  for(WebElement element : elements)
  {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
  }
  ```

Using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.rc-virtual-list-holder-inner div[title] > div"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class="rc-virtual-list-holder-inner"]//div[@title]/div"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```