# Getting empty string instead of Text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract only **all the links title** of a website and I did the following code. But getting only empty string.

```
String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/learning/learning-azure-sql-querying-18952522?trk=learning-serp_learning-search-card_search-card&upsellOrderOrigin=default_guest_learning";
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
String tempTitle = "";

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); // Chrome
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));


List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("table-of-contents__item-title"));
System.out.println(elements.size());

for (WebElement element : elements) {
    String title = element.getText().trim();
    titles.add(title);  
}

System.out.println(titles);
```

If i run tha program getting the below output:

```
27
[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

But i am trying to get only the titles from the page. Anybody can point out what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I just needed to replace `element.getText()` with `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")` instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To print the element texts ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55707593/7429447) and you can use the following solution:

- Code block:

  ```
  List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("table-of-contents__item-title")));
  for(WebElement element : elements)
  {
    String title = element.getText().trim();
    titles.add(title);
  }
  System.out.println(titles);
  ```

---

Using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following solution:

- Line of code:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("table-of-contents__item-title"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```