# How to print all the button texts within the url using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, java-stream

Steps:

- Go to the site > https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/
- Get a list of buttons from that page
- Print the name of the buttons that are displayed on the page.

Code trial:

```
package com.practice;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Buttons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\Oderint dum metuant\\eclipse-workspace\\JAR FILES\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/");

        List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
        for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++){
            WebElement button = buttons.get(i);
            if(button.isEnabled()){
                System.out.println(buttons);
                }}}}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please try to write Elaborated Questions [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using *By.tagName* method I used *By.cssSelector* method

here is the Working code...

```
package stackOverflow;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ToolsqaCom {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Tushar\\JARs\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    // WebElement b1 = driver.findElement(By.id("button1"));
    // l1.add(b1.getText());

    java.util.List<WebElement> b2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p button"));

    for (int i = 0; i < b2.size() - 1; i++) {
        String string = b2.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(string);

    }}}
```

Following is the Output:

> New Browser Window
>
> New Message Window
>
> New Browser Tab
>
> Alert Box
>
> Timing Alert
>
> Change Color
>
> Change Color
>
> Disabled

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to print the list of button names that are displayed on the page.

Ans.Remove if condition block and change the print statement. Refer below Code:

```
List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

    for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++)
    {
        WebElement button = buttons.get(i);

        System.out.println(button.getText());//It prints all the buttons name displayed on the page

    }
```

2. If you want to print the list of button names which are enabled on the page.

A. Keep the if condition block, just change the print statement. Refer below code:

```
List <WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));

        for ( int i=0; i<buttons.size();i++)
        {
            WebElement button = buttons.get(i);

            //System.out.println(button.getText());  //It prints all the buttons name displayed on the page

     if(button.isEnabled())
            {
                System.out.println(button.getText()); //It prints all the buttons name which are enabled on the page

            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all the button texts within the [url](https://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/) you can use *Java8's* `stream()` and `map()` and you can use the following solution:

- Line of code:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("button")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [New Browser Window, New Message Window, New Browser Tab, Alert Box, Timing Alert, Change Color, Change Color, Disabled, Visible, , , , ,  ,  ]
  ```