# Cannot cast from List<Functions.Function1<Object,String>> to List<String> creating a list from list of WebElements using Selenium and stream() Java8

Tags: java, selenium, stream, java-stream, webdriverwait

I'm trying to read an HTML table and get all the values into a 2d list using selenium. I'm using streamable to create a List inside another `map()` method. But I get `Cannot cast from List<Functions.Function1<Object,String>> to List<String>` error at nested `collect` method's line

#### HTML:

```
+--------+-------+
| r1 v1  | r1 v2 |
+--------+-------+
| r2 v1  | r2 v2 |
+--------+-------+

<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span>r1 v1</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span>r1 v2</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span>r2 v1</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <span>r2 v2</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Java Code:

```
public List getTableData() {
    return webElement
            .findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr"))
            .stream()
            .map(row -> {
                return row
                    .findElements(By.xpath(".//td/div/span"))
                    .stream()
                    .map(cell -> {
                        return cell
                            .getAttribute("innerText");
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // : Cannot cast from List<Functions.Function1<Object,String>> to List<String>
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Why am I gettting this error? How can I create a 2d List out of this table using java streamable?

Answer (score 1):

To create a *List* with the *innerText* using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following solution:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<String> myTexts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("table>tbody tr td span"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  List<String> myTexts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table/tbody//tr//td//span"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

> References: You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:
>
> - [How to extract the dynamic values of the id attributes of the table elements using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707227/how-to-extract-the-dynamic-values-of-the-id-attributes-of-the-table-elements-usi/55707593#55707593)
> - [How to print all the button texts within the url using Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388392/how-to-print-all-the-button-texts-within-the-url-using-selenium-through-java/56391361#56391361)

Comment: This way it's creating an array of values right? Right now I'm using for each parent loop and streamable as the inner loop