# What is the way to get a list of options that can be selected from a dropdown using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, java-stream, html-select

I want to get a list of all the options that can be selected from a dropdown menu in selenium using java. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried or the details about the java code?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768318/how-can-i-get-all-elements-from-drop-down-list-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

getAllSelectedOptions()

Refer this site for more information
https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select/getAllSelectedOptions

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to print the texts from the *option* elements of a [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu). Ideally while interacting with a [html-selct](/questions/tagged/html-selct) you need to use the [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772710/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-through-selenium-webdriver/49777340#49777340) Class. Further to interact with all the `<option>` tags you need to use [`getOptions()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684736/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-options-from-a-select-drop-down-using-selenium/56685051#56685051) method. As an example to print the texts from the *Day*, *Month* and *Year* `option` elements within [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) landing page `https://www.facebook.com/` you you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

Options from Day Dropdown using `id` attribute:

```
WebElement dayElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("day")));
Select selectDay = new Select(dayElement);
List<WebElement> dayList = selectDay.getOptions();
for (int i=0; i<dayList.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(dayList.get(i).getText());
```

Options from Month Dropdown using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) [`stream()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707227/how-to-extract-the-dynamic-values-of-the-id-attributes-of-the-table-elements-usi/55707593#55707593) and [`map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388392/how-to-print-all-the-button-texts-within-the-url-using-selenium-through-java/56391361#56391361):

```
Select selectMonth = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='month']"))));
List<String> myMonths = selectMonth.getOptions().stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  System.out.println(myMonths);
```

Console Output:

```
[Month, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec]
```

Options from Month Dropdown using [tag:css_selectors] and [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) [`stream()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520786/cannot-cast-from-listfunctions-function1object-string-to-liststring-creati/57523040#57523040) and [`map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117537/how-to-print-runs-scored-by-a-batsmen-in-a-scoreboard-format-webelements-through/62123047#62123047) in a single line of code:

```
System.out.println(new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select#year")))).getOptions().stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Console Output:

```
[Year, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962, 1961, 1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951, 1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945, 1944, 1943, 1942, 1941, 1940, 1939, 1938, 1937, 1936, 1935, 1934, 1933, 1932, 1931, 1930, 1929, 1928, 1927, 1926, 1925, 1924, 1923, 1922, 1921, 1920, 1919, 1918, 1917, 1916, 1915, 1914, 1913, 1912, 1911, 1910, 1909, 1908, 1907, 1906, 1905]
```

Answer (score 0):

This approch might help you to get understand how to get all selectable options from dropdown

```
driver.navigate().to("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10,100); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='/dropdown']"))).click();    
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='dropdown']"));
Select select = new Select(element);    
List<WebElement>allOptions = select.getOptions();
        allOptions.forEach(value->{System.out.println(value.getText());});
```