# How to extract only number from string

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to extract the prices from these page as text in USD from this
[site](https://www.wooloverslondon.com/new-styles?page=1&gender=161&style=77)

I used an locator `//span[@data-originalprice]` with get text of selenium
but still no only numbers, tried also split on `\\$` and nothing came
tried some regex `text.split("^-?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?$")` and still nothing.
looking for any idea?

Comment: Try xpath as ("//span[@data-originalprice]/span[2]")[20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract and print the *prices* trimming the *non-ASCII* characters you can use **`replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")`** and using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wooloverslondon.com/new-styles?page=1&gender=161&style=77");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.associated-product__price p>span"))).stream().map(element->element.getText().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wooloverslondon.com/new-styles?page=1&gender=161&style=77");
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='associated-product__price']//p/span"))).stream().map(element->element.getText().replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [7,035.00, 6,015.00, 6,015.00, 6,015.00, 6,015.00, 6,015.00, 6,015.00, 5,607.00, 5,607.00, 5,607.00, 4,996.00, 7,646.00]
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to extract the dynamic values of the id attributes of the table elements using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707227/how-to-extract-the-dynamic-values-of-the-id-attributes-of-the-table-elements-usi/55707593#55707593)
- [How to print all the button texts within the url using Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388392/how-to-print-all-the-button-texts-within-the-url-using-selenium-through-java/56391361#56391361)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that each element text contains non-ASCII charcters so i asked how to extract only the numbers without those non-ASCII charcters

Comment: @nuzooo Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you , just one more question: i see you reduced all non printable ASCII characters but how did you replace the rupy sign?

Comment: @nuzooo The rupy sign is a non-ASCII character as well which you wanted to get rid of.

Comment: Thank you again you are great

Comment: @nuzooo Feel free to visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.