# How to convert a web element's name store into string?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The below code stored a list of the web element name. Is there any way to convert in string

```
List<WebElement>title=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of storing the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you may like to store the *`textContent`* using Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following solution:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.document-card__details h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  List<String> titles = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='document-card__details']//h3"))).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to extract the dynamic values of the id attributes of the table elements using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707227/how-to-extract-the-dynamic-values-of-the-id-attributes-of-the-table-elements-usi/55707593#55707593)
- [How to print all the button texts within the url using Selenium through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388392/how-to-print-all-the-button-texts-within-the-url-using-selenium-through-java/56391361#56391361)

Comment: after execution O/P - THE NAME ARE [, , , , , ]

Comment: @SAM Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB it is working  . Any link can you gussets to read it more please .

Comment: Hi DebanjanB - the above code is now giving me all the  complete InnerHtml, instead of giving me the text inside that, how can I modify

Comment: @sam Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.