# Select Method Explained

Tags: java, selenium

i am new to Java and Selenium and try to learn
The Problem is, that i do not know how to extract names from a Dropdown Menu using the Select class

I have created a Variable Array String with the Expected Results
I have created a new object for Select Class and pass the xpath
I have created a List to store all the options from the Dropdown
Then i have a For Loop to iterate in all items in the loop and take the names
But i have no method to extract the name.
The question is how we can do that? Using the Select.

Thanks in advance for your help

Practice Website is this one: http://qaclickacademy.com/practice.php

HTML CODE:

```
<select id="dropdown-class-example" name="dropdown-class-example" wtx-context="4CBF2E98-EC2A-4384-8B92-4FB100C9F504" style="" xpath="1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="option1" style="">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

MY CODE:

```
String expectedDropDownItems [] = {"Select","option1","option2","option3"};
Select dropDownSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown-class-example")));
List<WebElement> dropDownActualValues = dropDownSelect.getOptions();
int counter = dropDownActualValues.size();
for (int i=0; i < counter; i++){

}
```

Expected and Actual something like this :

```
Selection 1 is : Select  
Selection 2 is : option1  
Selection 3 is : option2  
Selection 4 is : option3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all options in a drop-down list by Selenium WebDriver using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562853/how-to-get-all-options-in-a-drop-down-list-by-selenium-webdriver-using-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have all options in list of dropdown element from here you are very close to what you want. There is method on every web element from [WebElement Interface as getText()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--)

In your for loop it will look like as :

```
for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
            System.out.println("Selection " + i + " is : "  + dropDownActualValues.get(i).getText());
   }
```

***output***
Selection 0 is : Select
Selection 1 is : Option1
Selection 2 is : Option2
Selection 3 is : Option3

Comment: Thank a lot, yes i was trying to find getText, but i had to return the (i). Got it.